# horizontal Text on a circle

Tags: android

Hello i want to place several Text around a circle, but dont want to rotate it, the Text should be horizontal, like a speedometer. Rotate canvas or TextOnPath rotate the text, so its not horizontal.

How can i do this in Android?

```
        for (int i = minValue; i <= maxValue; ++i) {
        float y1 = scaleRect.top;
        float y2 = y1 - 0.020f;

        canvas.drawLine(0.5f, y1, 0.5f, y2, scalePaint);

            if (i%2==0) {
                String valueString = Integer.toString(i);
                canvas.drawText(valueString, 0.5f, y2 - 0.015f, scalePaint);
        }

        canvas.rotate(degreesPerNick, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int n = 10; // Anzahl Werte
float r = 0.28f; // Radius Kreis
for (int i = 0; i < (n); i++) 
{ 
    double fi = -2*Math.PI*i/n; 
    double x = r*Math.sin(fi + Math.PI) + 0.5f; 
    double y = r*Math.cos(fi + Math.PI) + 0.52f; 
    canvas.drawText(i+"", (float)x,(float)y , scalePaint);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a customized view for this. in onDraw method, create a path object, add circle to that object, and then use Canvas Object to draw text on that path.

```
Path path = new Path();
path.addCircle(x, y, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
myCanvas.drawTextOnPath(myText, path, offset, 0, myPaint);
```

Updated:::

Just need to create a round drawable like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="oval">
    <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
    <stroke android:color="@color/red" android:width="2dip"/>
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
</shape>
```

And set this drawable as your TextView background.